# Android Realm Update Asynchronously Using RxJava

Tags: android, asynchronous, realm, rx-java

I have this query to update data already in my realm table;

```
for (MyGameEntrySquad squad : response.body().getSquad()) {
            subscription = realm.where(RealmPlayer.class).equalTo("id", squad.getPlayer().getId())
                    .findFirstAsync()
                    .asObservable()
                    .subscribe(new Action1<RealmObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(RealmObject realmObject) {

                        }
                    });

}
```

I would like to perform this query asynchronously then display the results on the UI.

Basically, whatever is been returned by **response.body().getSquad()** has an id matching a record already in the DB; and that is what am using in my equalTo method.

Based on the data received, I would like to update two columns on each of the record matching the IDs.

However, I am facing a few challenges on this:

1. The Action1 in subscribe is returning a RealmObject instead of a PlayerObject
2. How to proceed from here

Any guidance on this will be appreciated.

Thanks

**Update**

```
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        //asynchronously update the existing players records with my squad i.e is_selected
        for (MyGameEntrySquad squad : response.body().getSquad()) {

            realm.where(RealmPlayer.class).equalTo("id", squad.getPlayer().getId())
                    .findFirstAsync()
                    .<RealmPlayer>asObservable()
                    .filter(realmPlayer -> realmPlayer.isLoaded())
                    .subscribe(player -> {
                        realm.beginTransaction();
                        if (squad.getPlayer().getPosition().equals("GK")) {
                            player.setPlaygroundPosition("gk");
                            player.setIsSelected(true);
                        }

                        // pick the flex player
                        if (squad.isFlex()) {
                            player.setPlaygroundPosition("flex");
                            player.setIsSelected(true);
                        }

                        // pick the Goalie
                        if (squad.getPlayer().getPosition().equals("GK")) {
                            player.setPlaygroundPosition("gk");
                            player.setIsSelected(true);
                        }

                        // pick the DFs
                        if ((squad.getPlayer().getPosition().equals("DF")) && (!squad.isFlex())) {
                            int dfCounter = 1;
                            player.setPlaygroundPosition(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "df%d", dfCounter));
                            player.setIsSelected(true);
                            dfCounter++;
                        }

                        // pick the MFs
                        if ((squad.getPlayer().getPosition().equals("MF")) && (!squad.isFlex())) {
                            int mfCounter = 1;
                            player.setPlaygroundPosition(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "mf%d", mfCounter));
                            player.setIsSelected(true);
                            mfCounter++;
                        }

                        // pick the FWs
                        if ((squad.getPlayer().getPosition().equals("FW")) && (!squad.isFlex())) {
                            int fwCounter = 1;
                            player.setPlaygroundPosition(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "mf%d", fwCounter));
                            player.setIsSelected(true);
                            fwCounter++;
                        }

                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(player);
                        realm.commitTransaction();
                        updateFieldPlayers();


                    });

        }

        hideProgressBar();

    }
```

Comment: So when do you unsubscribe your subscribers? You **do** unsubscribe, right? Where do you "update the two columns"? How are you showing the objects (is it a RecyclerView or something else)? What thread is this example code running on? Currently there isn't enough data available to properly answer this question.

Comment: Hi @EpicPandaForce, part of the challenge I was facing was proceeding from that point and that is why some information was missing. I am editing the original question to show where am currently at

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes I unsubscribe; at the onDestroy() function. I am using TableLayout for now

Comment: why not `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce My UseCase does not need a RecyclerView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
realm.where(RealmPlayer.class).equalTo("id", squad.getPlayer().getId())
                        .findFirstAsync()
                        .<RealmPlayer>asObservable()
                        .subscribe(new Action1<RealmPlayer>() {
                            @Override
                            public void call(RealmPlayer player) {

                            }
                        });
```

You should do like that.

Btw, it's bad idea to do it in a cycle - check [**in**](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#in-java.lang.String-java.lang.Boolean:A-) method of RealmQuery.

Comment: Hi @Divers,

Thanks for your answer.

I however did not understand the last point.

The data from **response.body().getSquad()** is from a HTTP request which am using to update the already existing data

Comment: Do not do a lot of realm queries, but instead get list of `squad.getPlayer().getId()` and use `in` realm query to fetch data in one query. If your question is answered, please close it with marking answer as right one.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (MyGameEntrySquad squad : response.body().getSquad()) { // btw why is this not `Observable.from()`?
        subscription = realm.where(RealmPlayer.class).equalTo("id", squad.getPlayer().getId())
                .findFirstAsync()
                .asObservable()
```

This should not be on the UI thread. It should be on a background thread. On a background thread, you need to use synchronous query instead of async query.

Even on the UI thread, you'd still need to `filter(RealmObject::isLoaded)` because it's an asynchronous query, and in case of `findFirstAsync()` you need to filter for `RealmObject::isValid` as well.

For this case, you would not need `asObservable()` - [this method is for observing a particular item and adding a `RealmChangeListener` to it](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149). Considering this should be on a background thread with synchronous query, this would not be needed (non-looper background threads cannot be observed with `RealmChangeListener`s).

You should also unsubscribe from any subscription you create when necessary.

And yes, to obtain `RealmPlayer` in `asObservable()`, use `.<RealmPlayer>asObservable()`.

In short, you should put that logic on a background thread, and listen for changes on the UI thread. Background thread logic must be done with the synchronous API. You will not need `findFirstAsync` for this.